# Matlab: Counting the occurences of each element and sorting

Tags: matlab, sorting

I can use `sort` like this to sort elements in an array.

```
M = sort(A(:));
```

But is there a good method to sort the elements with its occurrences as well?

Like this:

```
ELEM = [10, 60, 30, 20]
OCCU = [30, 25, 10, 5]
```

Comment: _"Like this"_ I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. Please add examples of your desired input and output.

Comment: I think you are looking for the second output of `[sorted,idx] = sort()`

Comment: Thanks very much for your great answer, I solved it! But one problem remains, my original array A is a 2d array. Can I get row and column separately?

Comment: You may have a look at [`ind2sub`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the above with combination of [`unique()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`sort()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html).

First extract only the unique values in the vector using [`unique()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and group the same indices for occurrence.
Then just sort the values and you'll have what you asked above.